# Pytorch fails with CUDA error: device-side assert triggered

Tags: pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to initialize a tensor on jupyerlab with GPU enabled.

`device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')`

`x= torch.rand(1,10).to(device)`

But I am getting this strange error.

pytorch can detect gpu but when i tries to do something, it get's an error

Comment: "pytorch can detect gpu", how did you check that exactly?

Comment: import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
torch.cuda.device_count()
 
i got the results from all these commands

Comment: What is your pytorch/cudatoolkit versions and cuda driver version?

Comment: i checked three versions and three were compatible when i found compatiblity on pytorch docs